# List to string with separators

Tags: python, json, string, list

I am trying to pass a command line arguments to AWS lambda as a event json.
I have a list out of the command line args like:

```
['engine', '-e', '100', '-w', '4']
```

When I pass this list I want to it get passed as:

```
'engine', '-e', '100', '-w', '4'
```

I am trying to use it like this:

```py
listcommd = ['engine', '-e', '100', '-w', '4']
command = ["--bucket", "mybucket", f"{listcommand}"]
```

I want the end result to look like:

```py
command = ["--bucket", "mybucket", 'engine', '-e', '100', '-w', '4']
```

but it is looking like:

```py
command = ["--bucket", "mybucket", "['engine', '-e', '100', '-w', '4']"]
```

Comment: You can use splat operator instead of formatting: `["--bucket", "mybucket", *listcommd]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists support concatenation. Just do this:

```py
command = ["--bucket", "mybucket"] + listcommand
```